# Implement thread lock with objective c

Tags: java, objective-c, multithreading, locking

I'm developing an iOS 5 and above with latest SDK.

I have to implement a synchronized method with a `Thread Lock` in Objective C.

This is the Java version of what I have to do:

```
public abstract class MyClass 
{
    [ ... ]

    private static Object dataLock = new Object();

    public static long dataId = 0;

    [ ... ]

    public static void PostData(byte[] data)
    {
        synchronized (MyClass.getDataLock())
        {
            dataId++;
            MyClass.getDataLock().notify();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] GetData()
    {
        synchronized (MyClass.getDataLock())
        {
            try
            {
                MyClass.getDataLock().wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {}

            return MyClass.getData();
        }
    }

    [ ... ]
}
```

**How do I implement `dataLock` in Objective C? As a `NSObject`?**
**How can I do `PostData` and `GetData` methods in Objective C?**

Comment: Thanks to voting Close and don't say why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `NSCondition` class.  E.g.:

```
static NSCondition* g_dataLock = nil;

...

+ (void)initialize
{
    if (self == [MyClass class])
    {
        g_dataLock = [NSCondition new];
    }
}

+ (void)postData:(NSData*)data
{
    [g_dataLock lock];
    dataId++;
    [g_dataLock signal];
    [g_dataLock unlock];
}

+ (NSData*)getData
{
    NSData* data = nil;

    [g_dataLock lock];
    [g_dataLock wait];

    data = ...

    [g_dataLock unlock];

    return data;
}
```

See the [Thread Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In your answer, you've added this method `+ (void)initialize` but, is it compatible with an `abstract class`? I know that `Objective C` doesn't have `abstract` classes, but I want to try create something similar on Objective C.

Comment: @VansFannel Since your Java code used static methods, I used Obj-C class methods in my example.  +initialize is a class method that is called exactly once for every class, before a class is first used.  That method is often used for performing any class-level initialization, like the dataLock in your example.

Comment: So, if I use `+initialize` I don't need to use class methods, isn't it? Thanks.

Comment: It's just a method you can use to initialize global data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @synchronized(dataLock){...code here...} but it's not the fastest way as described [here](http://perpendiculo.us/?p=133).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I implement `dataLock` in Objective C? As a `NSObject`?

Comment: You can add something like static const NSString *syncString = @"Synchronize" on top of .m file and synchronize on it, or just synchronize on self. It's probably not needed to have dataLock object in class.

Comment: Well, this is only a piece of code. On `MyClass` there are six or seven locks. Thanks for your answer.